# How do I set a page's base href in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, href, radix

I want to set a page's base href attribute in Javascript based off of the current hostname. I have generated HTML pages that can be viewed on different hostnames, which means generating a base href tag will work in one hostname but will be incorrect in the other.

Comment: I usually have a constants JS file that I include which i set `$.serverRoot` to be the relative root of the host (e.g. `$.serverRoot = '/myapp/';`

Comment: That works for things like AJAX requests, but if I were to adjust all of the image paths and link hrefs to account for a Javascript variable I'd have to do a tremendous amount of work. Using the base href tag solves a lot of problems I was having with having the same HTML file accessible on different hostnames, but it introduced the problem of incorrect paths on one hostname.

Answer (score 44):

The correct way of doing this is to do a document.write of the tag based off the current hostname:

**Correct:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<base href='http://" + document.location.host + "' />");
</script>
```

This method has produced correct results in IE, FF, Chrome, and Safari. It produces a (correct) different result than doing the following:

**Incorrect:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var newBase = document.createElement("base");
newBase.setAttribute("href", document.location.hostname);
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newBase);
</script>
```

Comment: I have run into some trouble with Google's crawler while using this method. I didn't put a space between ' and />", and the crawler is intepreting my base href as document.location.hostname'/>. This may be a problem with this solution. For more information, see: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=2cff8eadfdf3a393&hl=en&fid=2cff8eadfdf3a393000498a325f9c75d

Comment: There is no reason presented why `document.write` would be “correct” and proper insertion of a node in the document tree would be “incorrect”. The question falls into the category “solving the wrong problem”, but the approach described as “correct” here would often insert a `base` tag in a wrong place, to begin with. If the code is in the `head` part, it’s rather useless (why not put the right `base` tag there as normal HTML?), and if it is executed elsewhere, it will usually insert `base` into `body`.

Comment: I'm curious as to why the "incorrect" method is incorrect.

Comment: The "incorrect" method does not actually work. The only way to get the browser to dynamically change its base href is the "correct" method.

Comment: Hi! According to my tests in my angular enabled web page, the document.write mode don't seem to add the base tag until it is too late. I have compared the markup when adding it with javascript or hard-coding it in the markup, looks the same but js solution don't apply any base tag functionality even though "looks" like it is in place... Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldnt `http:` be `document.location.protocol` ?

Comment: I'm finding that on initial load, even though document.write is above stylesheet links and other assets, Chrome is first looking for files at the original url, and then trying again using the contents of <base />.

For instance, if my original URL is http://site.dev/account, and the result of the document.write is setting base to http://site.dev/, the assets are first trying to load from /account/, the server returns a 404, then they correctly load from http://site.dev/.

Comment: I'd just like to add a refinement: `document.location.protocol + '//' + document.location.hostname + ( document.location.port ? ':' : '' ) + document.location.port + document.location.pathname + '" />' + document.head.innerHTML` - this makes it more portable, for running on a specific port, such as in Webpack. this fixed a problem with Webpack for me, where Webpack can't write a different path for images in CSS than for images in HTML (they're all relative paths or all absolute paths, but not both, which prevents the app from being portable.)

Comment: It would be great if this answer provided valuable information like... the answer to "why?"

Comment: Considering the <base> is appended directly under the <script> tag... this "correct" method is basically useless, just use the `<base>` tag like normally. In fact, if you run the JS code in the devtool's console, it'll empty the entire DOM leaving just the base tag!

The real correct method would be to use the `document.head.innerHTML = "<base href=''>" + document.head.innerHTML` as it ensures every element uses the new baseHref.

Answer (score 14):

I think you'd better do it this way

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.head.innerHTML = document.head.innerHTML + "<base href='" + document.location.href + "' />";
    </script>
```

As `location.hostname` does not return the application context root! You could also log the `document.location` on the console `console.log` to see all available metadata on `document.location`.

Comment: This is actually more proper these days (than using `document.write`). On a practical note: this worked for me in jsFiddle while `document.write` didn't.

Comment: The ideal way would be to do `document.head.innerHTML = "<base href=''>" + document.head.innerHTML` (base first, then innerHTML) for two reasons: 1. Any <link> tags, <script> tags, etc in the <head> making use of the relative path, won't be able to since the <base> is being appended below them. 2. If you execute the code twice or more, the most recent execution becomes the <base> tag that works (because it's whichever is topmost that works and this code "prepends").

Answer (score 6):

I have to disagree with the top answer. It does not account for the protocol so it will fail.

A working solution that I have to account for protocol / host / port is the following

```
    var base = document.createElement('base');
    base.href = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port : '');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(base);
```

This currently works fine in all major browsers including IE11

I have used this to make an npm package that also supports adding a suffix to the end of this base href if anyone is interested

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamic-base

https://github.com/codymikol/dynamic-base

Comment: The `<base>` tag allows relative paths... this is pointless...

Comment: Don't assume your usecase is the only one : V ). This post is from 2019 and having a fully qualified base href was required for me to use the ui.router library for angularjs and my application was hosted across many different domains.

Comment: I don't get that because ["Absolute and relative URLs are allowed"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base#href), was that changed since 2019? Edit: Just checked [the history](https://github.com/mdn/content/blob/52411dce188780abafbedd188a9e4ff15c0fb76d/files/en-us/web/html/element/base/index.md) doesn't seem to have changed since 2021. I think this was just a misconception, because unless it was changed, quite a few people seem to assume that <base> requires an absolute URL.

Comment: Sure, but what if an external library that you don't have control of reads the base href and that particular library requires that to be a fully qualified url?

Comment: The relative path you set is converted into an absolute url. If you do `document.baseUri` or inspect the properties of any element, you can see the `baseHref` property for each element on the DOM. The base href will be a "fully qualified url" based on the relative path you input into the `<base href="">` tag.

Answer (score 2):

document.write("");

```html
<script>
document.write("<base href='"+ window.location.protocol +'//' + window.location.host + "' >");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.document.head.innerHTML=`<base href=${href}>`+window.document.head.innerHTML;
```

The href variable is the href you want to use.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).