# Appending base tag to head with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Can you append a `base` tag to the head of a document from a `div` in the `body` of the document using JavaScript? By that, I mean, what are some drawbacks of doing that? My concern is that I'll run into a sort of race condition because the `base` tag is understood to exist in the `head` so it won't get respected if the page has already been rendered. I haven't yet experienced this problem, but I was wondering whether it should be a concern.

To be clear, I know *how* do this via JavaScript. My question is whether the tag will be respected/honored if it's appended to the DOM after the page loads/renders...

My code is an HTML fragment that is likely to appear in the `body`, but I need to set the `base` tag because my assets are referenced relatively. Let's assume that I can't change that (because I can't. At least, not right away). You can also assume that setting the `base` won't break anything that's not my HTML fragment and that there are no other `base` tags...ever.

Comment: Wouldn't setting a `base` to make your relative references work potentially break other references on the page?

Comment: We can assume that that won't happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be wrong (or partially wrong depending on how each browser chose to implement that), but AFAIK the document URL base is parsed only once. By the time you append that BASE Element to the DOM it is already too late.

**EDIT: Looks like I was wrong**

Apparently, [there is a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494954/how-do-i-set-a-pages-base-href-in-javascript). But there are also downsides about search engines.

Comment: Ah, yes, I have heard this. But what happens if the page loads, there's no `base` tag, then some JavaScript appends a `base` tag to the DOM? Will that tag get respected?

Comment: What I mean is: the URL base is set on the HEAD, and before parsing/executing anything from the body. And once it is set, appending a BASE element won't help. But I didn't do the experiment.

Comment: I still wonder whether that `document.write` works 100% of the time in the `body` tag...

Comment: document.write works because it is rewriting the HTML the browser will parse. So it is triggering parse and then the whole circuit, BASE tags included. However, note that what you output with document.write goes right there where the script is located. So I'm not sure you will gain much compared with, say, a PHP tag.

Comment: By PHP tag (or ASP tag, or JSP tag) I mean, write that value from the server side, something like `<base href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/folder" />`.

I'm assuming there is a server-side script generating the web page dynamically, and also that you can edit that script. Maybe I shouldn't.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, for example:

```
<script>
var base = document.createElement('base');
base.href = 'http://www.w3.org/';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(base);
</script>
```

I don’t see *why* you would want to do this, but it’s possible.

Comment: My main concern is that if you do this after the page has loaded/been rendered, the `base` tag is ignored/not honored. Is that a valid concern?

Comment: You seem to have changed the question. Regarding the drawbacks that you are now asking about, the most obvious is that the technique won’t work when scripting is disabled (so search engines will get a wrong view of the document). Please explain the *original* problem instead of an assumed solution. If you can only work with a fragment of HTML, then it’s generally a wrong approach to try to do something that has global effect.

Answer (score 2):

Jukka to answer **your question of WHY** you would want to do it that way.

**Example.**

A mobile application such as `phonegap` that is a thin wrapper around a webapp, but smart enough to know if it's running in a browser or on the device.

Once it knows that it's on a device, then it needs to know the base `url` so it can properly locate everything that was previously referenced as relative `URL`s.

In our case, we have 4 different systems, `dev`, `test`, `beta` & `live`, each with different `URL`s.

Usually changes are incremental, but a lot of times we do want to test back and forth between each system, for instance in a/b testing.

Since the routing layouts are basically identical, switching back and forth on the base `URL` makes a lot of sense.

Remember many web apps use a static asset such as an html page for the application skeleton, javascript for the glue logic and a web based backend that is really nothing more than a thin layer over a DB. eg MEAN apps are frequently this way.

Building your apps **this way provides a phenomenal speed up in scalability and responsiveness** since the "web" server doesn't have to slow down long enough to construct the page view as happens in template languages.

Anyways setting the base `url` means being able to change where the app sources it's data on the fly and can be incredible speed up for developer productivity due to code reuse.

Answer (score 0):

Search engines?
There was a time when search engines crawling bots did not "understand" or run any of the Javascript code. In this case, such bots would get all the links wrong and the crawling would stop right there.

So basically it might hamper some crawlers from crawling and indexing your links.