# Is there a header alternative to <base>?

Tags: html, http

Might be an ignorant question but my client-side application now uses  to get it's resources. The html for that page is rendered by my server which involves a template engine and a template variable because the base url changes. So was wondering if there is an alternative to base (maybe a header?). That way I can let my server just serve html and set the header and not have to deal with a template engine and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document controls BASE, not the protocol (HTTP). You can, however, use JavaScript to change this value.

See: [How do I set a page's base href in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494954/how-do-i-set-a-pages-base-href-in-javascript)

Comment: Was afraid it wouldn't be possible.